# Apex Strings : Pipe symbol (|) is converted to &#124; in string variable while querying

Tags: apex, soql, string

I'm trying to query a field on Object__c which stores information like (1001|01).

Example:

```
String str = '\'1001|01\'';
List<Object__c> recordList = [SELECT ID FROM Object__c WHERE Field__c includes (:str) LIMIT 50000];
```

Exception Message is shown as below:

```
"common.apex.runtime.impl.ExecutionException: expecting a right parentheses, found '&#124;'"
```

Below are the list of things I have already tried to stop pipe symbol from getting converted into it's Unicode:

1. unescapeHtml4()

```
System.debug(str.unescapeHtml4());
```

2. EncodingUtils.urlDecode();

```
String str = '\'1001%7C01\''; // %7C is equivalent to pipe (|) symbol
System.debug(EncodingUtil.urlDecode(str, 'UTF-8'));
```

3. replace() and replaceAll() methods to convert `&#124;` to pipe symbol dynamically

All the above ways failed to get the required results.

Any other help or direction would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: what is a field type of `Object__c.Field__c` ?

Comment: Hi @OleksandrBerehovskyi It's Picklist (Multi-Select)

Comment: so you want to query record, where `Field__c` includes value `1001` or `01` values, right? in this example `|` is just a separator between two values of multi-select picklist? Please provide example of input data, and what is the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

The error you're seeing is actually just how the platform likes to encode some characters as part of an error response, and has nothing to do with your problem. The error is telling you, quite misleadingly, that you've done something fundamentally wrong with your code.

If `Field__c` is not a multi-select picklist, you can't use `includes`/`excludes`, and can cause errors like this. You need to use `LIKE`, `IN`, etc.

If you forget a `:` when binding a variable, you can get all kinds of random errors from the compiler/runtime, often in dramatic ways depending on exactly what you've done.

If you're actually using Dynamic SOQL, you're not allowed to bind to complex objects, only simple variables. For example, `String query = 'select id from account where name = :names[0]';` isn't allowed if `names` is a `List<String>`.

Here's a brief proof that there's nothing inherently wrong with pipes:

```
// Execute Anonymous Script
insert new Account(Name='\'1001|01\'');
String str = '\'1001|01\'';
List<Account> recordList = [SELECT ID FROM Account WHERE Name = :str]; 
System.assertEquals(1, recordList.size());
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. The field type is multi select picklist so we're using includes keyword.

Comment: @VishalTiwari Okay, but my answer is still valid-ish. You're doing something the compiler/SOQL runtime doesn't like, and it has nothing to do with `|`. Unfortunately, the code you posted is anonymized to a point where we can't tell what the original problem is. You think you know where the problem is because of that error, but it's a common, misleading error. Your problem is how you've written your specific implementation of the query.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the semicolon in the SOQL, just keep it like your code but the soql like this:

```
List<Object__c> recordList = [SELECT ID FROM Object__c WHERE Field__c includes (:str) LIMIT 50000];
```

Comment: That was a typo from my side. Fixed it in the post, however not the underlying problem. Thanks anyway though